# Trying to get HH:MM:SS from milliseconds in Presto

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I'm trying to convert milliseconds to format HH:MM:SS or MM:SS, but I keep getting the same error.

Here's the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. SYNTAX_ERROR: line 5:19: Unexpected parameters (time, varchar(5)) for function date_format. Expected: date_format(timestamp with time zone, varchar(x)) , date_format(timestamp, varchar(x))  [Execution ID: 89bfd858-9992-439f-ad84-b59bfd1cbde8]
```

Here's my code:

```
SELECT
  column_a,
  round(AVG((milliseconds) / 1000)) AS Seconds,
  (case when milliseconds/1000 < 60 * 60
             then time '00:00:00' + milliseconds * interval '1' second, '%i:%s'
             else time '00:00:00' + milliseconds * interval '1' second, '%H:%i:%s'
        end) as hhmmss,
  round((AVG((column_b)) / 1099511627776),2) AS b, 
  COUNT(column_c) AS c
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  column_a
```

Tried with this one as well

```
(case when milliseconds/1000 < 60 * 60
                 then date_format(time '00:00:00' + milliseconds * interval '1' second, '%i:%s')
                 else date_format(time '00:00:00' + milliseconds * interval '1' second, '%H:%i:%s')
            end) as hhmmss
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast your time to timestamp:

```sql
select date_format(cast(time '00:00:00' + 23 * interval '1' second as timestamp), '%H:%i:%s')
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 00:00:23 |

Note that this will work only if you have less than 24 hours interval in your `milliseconds`, otherwise you will need to do math yourself and concat results into desired string.

P.S. Should not `milliseconds * interval '1' second` be `(milliseconds/1000) * interval '1' second`?